# Find the flaw in my 1-page proof of the Four Color Theorem

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, coloring

The Four Color Theorem has been proven for quite a while now, so I'm not really breaking ground there. But last night, for some reason, it popped into my head and I started thinking about it. I feel I have devised a very simple proof, but all previous proofs (of which I am aware) have required a fair amount of computer-aided calculation. Ergo, it does not pass the smell test.

While it is not a rigorous proof, it seems relatively intuitively clear. Is there something I am missing or have I actually stumbled onto something interesting? While, I'm assuming that I have missed something, it will bug me if I don't know where my logical lapse occurred. So here is my (informal) proof:

(1) Any contiguous map of simple polygons has a corresponding map of vertices with non-intersecting paths connecting them; these paths do not need to be straight lines (and in many cases cannot be straight). Each vertex maps to one polygon and each path maps to one shared edge. Such a corresponding map can be generated by following this procedure: choose a single point in each polygon to be the corresponding vertex; from each of these vertices draw a curve to the center of each shared edge of the corresponding polygon.

The curves can be drawn without intersection for any simple polygon: the edges have order*, there is a path of finite width to each edge, and an arbitrarily large number of parallel lines can pass through any finite width.

*This is to say that one can choose any edge and travel the polygon perimeter clockwise or counterclockwise about an internal point to produce an ordered sequence of edges.

(2) Considering such a map of vertices, any three mutually connected vertices reduce to a triangle.

[image]

(3) Adding a fourth mutually connected vertex requires placing the vertex either inside or outside of the triangle. In both cases, the structure reduces to the following:

[image]

(4) Adding a fifth mutually connected vertex requires placing the vertex inside one of the triangles or outside of all of them. In the first case, the path connecting to the internal vertex must intersect one of the already existing paths. In the second case, the path connecting to the external vertex must intersect one of the already existing paths.

[image]

(5) Therefore, one cannot have five mutually connected vertices without intersection. Equivalently, there cannot be five contiguous simple polygons that mutually share edges.

(6) Therefore, one never needs more than four colors to fill in a contiguous map of simple polygons, such that no two adjacent (edge-sharing) polygons have the same color.

Comment: Comment about (1): "these paths do not need to be straight lines (and in many cases cannot be straight)", the graph you are talking about is the dual graph, which is planar too, and every planar graph has an straight-line embedding in the plane.

Comment: You proved that the graph $K_5$ is not planar. So given a graph you won't find a $K_5$ subgraph. That doesn't prove the 4 colour theorem.

Comment: See [Alfred Kempe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Kempe) and [Four Color Theorem: History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem#History).

Comment: FPE, I suspected there was a straight-line embedding, but I wasn't certain, and it was not necessary for the argument. I should have left out the assertion that some lines cannot be straight.

Comment: @Darth Geek, thanks for the direction. As I stated, I figured something was off, and clearly my approach was naive. Cheers.

Comment: @JayB. Not a problem. It happens to all of us.

Comment: A theorem by Erdos (what's it called again...) showed that there are graph with arbitrary large girth and arbitrary large chromatic number. It illustrate how colouring is a global property rather than local: no matter how far you look locally, if you have no take the whole graph into account, there exist a graph with very large chromatic number that locally looks like a 2-colourable graph.

Comment: @Lucian, thanks for the link; I hadn't realized my considerations boiled down to Kempe's approach. It's been a long time since I've endeavored upon mathematical proofs, clearly my intuitions are a bit rusty.

Comment: @DarthGeek, just a quick follow-up. So, I'm presuming that the way to go about it is to show that, for a complete planar map of some size, regardless of external inputs that map can be colored with only four colors. Then, clearly, all smaller maps (complete or incomplete) are colorable, and larger maps can be broken down into connected patches, with all the central patches proven colorable regardless of inputs. This leaves only the peripheries, which are then just partials of the colorable map, and can be aligned to ensure colorability. I guess this is where the computer enters into it...

Comment: complete may not be the right word, but maximal permissible connectivity is essentially what I mean

Comment: @Gina I love that theorem - it's Erdös-Szekeres.